# Getting HTML from a logged-in site

Tags: android, html, cookies, jsoup

I am developing an Android app in which I need to get the information from a website that requires login  credentials. 
After login it will display the home page, then clicking a button will direct it to the data page.

I am getting the HTML of the login page and sending the user ID and password to it. It is successful and I am getting the HTML code of the home page, and now I am making another request for the useful data.

I am passing the cookie information along with the URL but it is redirecting to login page. Am I  missing any other vital Information that I need to pass?

```
// Login code

Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Method.GET);
Response response = connection.execute();
                                         cookies = response.cookies();
                                         doc = response.parse();
                                         Element viewstateNode = doc.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE");
                                         Element eventvalidationNode = doc.getElementById("__EVENTVALIDATION");

                                         String viewStateValue = viewstateNode.attr("value");
                                         String eventValidationValue = eventvalidationNode.attr("value");
                                         connection = Jsoup.connect(url)
                                                                   .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewStateValue)
                                                                   .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidationValue)
                                                                   .data("txtLoginID", username)
                                                                   .data("txtPWD", password)
                                                                   .data("btnLogin", "Go%21")
                                                                   .followRedirects(true)
                                                                   .userAgent("Google")
                                                                   .cookies(cookies)
                                                                   .maxBodySize(100000)
                                                                   .timeout(60000);
                                     response = connection.method(Method.POST).execute();
                                     doc = response.parse();

// Doc contains the HTML code of next page after successful login. Now I need to get the HTML code of next page with useful data.
// I am using the following code to make the second request. 

Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url_datapage)
                .cookies(cookies)
                .userAgent("Google")
                .maxBodySize(100000)
                .timeout(60000)
                .method(Method.GET);
         Response response = connection.execute();
         doc = response.parse();
```

But `doc` contain the HTML code of login page. It is redirecting to home page again.

Comment: `I am using following code to make the second request`. Well it is your third actually. Please elaborate.

Comment: content edited, please check now.

Comment: There are still three `execute()` calls. So the last one would be the third request. Not?

Comment: yes. That has to get the HTML code of datapage. though I am sending the cookie information along with the third call its redirecting to login page. do I need to pass any extra information ?

Comment: Then please edit your post again if it concerns the third one. The cookie information retrieved by which call? The first or the second?

Comment: I solved this. I have to pass the cookie that I am getting after successful login. Thanks every one.

Comment: Indeed. You took the wrong one.

Comment: ya buddy your last comment made me think so. Thank you :)